# Add row duplicated for a value missed in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a row that is a duplicate of the previous one for a missed value

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,5,6,7], 'B':['green','red','blue','blue','black','white','green']})
```

In this case the missed value in A column is 4 so I want add row with value 4 in column A and blue in column B because is the value of the previuos row

Desired Output

```
    A   B
0   0   green
1   1   red
2   2   blue
3   3   blue
4   4   blue
5   5   black
6   6   white
7   7   green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use A as a temporary index to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = (df.set_index('A')
         .reindex(range(df['A'].min(), df['A'].max()+1), method='ffill')
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   A      B
0  0  green
1  1    red
2  2   blue
3  3   blue
4  4   blue
5  5  black
6  6  white
7  7  green
```